# Webcomic / site identification

Tags: story-identification, webcomics, manga

Not sure if this the right place to ask, bit here goes.

I'm trying to find a comic / manga site that I'm certain begins with a j. I'm also pretty sure the logo was a stylised fox, and I've seen ads floating around for it.

The site had a model where you buy comics with tokens, and you can get the whole series or single items.

I think one of the more popular series they had was about a group of people in some sort of videogame.

I also seem to recall a series where there was a hero (possibly his"job" was being a hero) who was fighting a dragon that was merged with a young girl, it was some sort of family curse. Also in that series there was a sentient castle that he persuaded to fight for him rather than his enemies.

Either the site or the individual stories would be great.

Comment: http://www.userlogos.org/files/logos/Daggles/mangafox.png

Comment: Nope, not that I'm afraid. I think it was red, with no text. Kinda reminded me of the metal gear solid FOX logo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally stumbled across it, the site is called [Lehzin](https://www.lezhin.com/en), with the comics in question being [4 Cut Hero](https://www.lezhin.com/en/comic/4cuthero) and [RPG Comic](https://www.lezhin.com/en/comic/rpgcomic)

Comment: Hi Lewis! It's been a while but could you maybe self-accept your answer? Keeps stuff organized :) And if you could turn it into a full-feldged answer, with quotes/pictures matching what you remembered, it would be even greater!

Comment: I'll sort out the rest in a bit