# Post-apocalyptic webcomic. Hero is a former doctor turned android, named something like Abe or Aron

Tags: story-identification, robots, post-apocalyptic, webcomics

I've been looking for this one over several months. Webomic was ongoing 2 years ago, I was really hooked up. Thing is I don't remember anything except little details of plot like:

1. Post-apocalyptic (kinda)
2. Main dude is a badass android/robot with a hat and yellow-ish trenchcoat with pistol. I am trying really hard to remember his name but several months no results. I think it was Abe/Aron or something like that but again no search results.
3. He finds a boy in a wasteland and (I don't remember why exactly, plotwise) he is protecting him like a badass later against some corporation mercs in white armor. Also he's like a mentor to him.
4. He was once human doctor and had daughter. Later he got transformed into android.
5. There also was an amazing fight with a...werewolf-robot in jacket and tie? He was serving/helping some woman who was important to plot

Comment: I believe chicks prefer to be called ladies nowadays.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the style it was drawn in? Was it physically published or a webcomic?

Comment: It was a webcomic and the style was like top tier professional level. Can't describe it better :d I'm not that into comics and lack knowledge of different styles.  sorry. Also remembered that the main villain was some mega corporation dude who wanted to turn people into androids. It was his ,,vision of future,, kind of. And the main protagonist ( the former human/doctor android ) was regretting that he has a life as robot/android now.

Comment: Also #valorum :D she was anything but lady trust me :D blasting enemies left and right. Didn't mean to insult anyone.

Comment: @Valorum:  Not all women are ladies.

Comment: Any recollection of the website you read it on? Webtoon, Tapastic, other?

Comment: Website i was reading had a thing, it would allow you read certain chapters as they came out but some time had to pass before they became free to read. Otherwise you had to buy some coins/points to spend them on unlocking newly releasee chapters that were ,,locked,,

Comment: FINALLY! someone helped me on other forum. For those curious its called ,,dogma,, :D thank you all for the time guys!

Comment: @Alex You can accept Jenayah's answer below, if that's the same *Dogma*, by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 7):

Pretty sure what you're after is [*Dogma*](https://www.lezhin.com/en/comic/dogma_en) by Kemi, hosted on Lezhin.

> A world where machines yearn to understand and become humans and where one human seeks to become as strong and indestructible as these machines. A jam-packed action SF that will blow your mind away.

[image: Robot with a yellow trenchcoat and kid]

I can only read the first chapter without an account, but [the robot does find a kid inside a fridge in a garbage dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLNBA.png). There is also a flashback with a doctor-looking man, and the thumbnails for chapter 4 and 5 have a fight against a villainous-looking girl.

---

As you said it was a webcomic, I browsed our [webcomics](/questions/tagged/webcomics) questions on the off chance it had been asked before. It hadn't, but when you [commented](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205657/post-apocalyptic-comic-hero-is-a-former-doctor-turned-android-named-something#comment562150_205657) that the site you read it on had a "thing about coins/points to spend them on unlocking newly releasee chapters", I remembered having read this question: [Webcomic / site identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/172591/). I fetched the answer there (Lehzin), Googled `webcomic robot site:lezhin.com`, and bingo.

Comment: If this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Comment: Aaaand, this is my 100th story-ID answer! [Champagne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O9he.gif)!